# Can't use the sandbox

Tags: support, sandbox

I am new to the community and I have been advised to use the sandbox to edit long posts so as not to disturb the frontpage of the site. But I think I am not able to use it yet because I can't "edit" the answers of the sandbox.

What should I do to keep editing my long posts?

Comment: The sandbox was useful in some ways that no longer pertain.  I would advise you to simply edit your "long posts" in place or use such third-party sites as [StackEdit](https://stackedit.io/editor) until you've reached the (fairly high) reputation threshold to edit posts.  It seems a bit unexpected that a reputation limit applies to editing Community Wiki posts, but I don't think there is a quick fix if that is how StackExchange works for the time being.

Comment: Thank you indeed for the quick feedback!

Comment: The privilege to Edit Community Wiki answers, which is what you will need, comes with 100 reputation points (earned on the main site).  See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki).

Comment: @hardmath Why do you think that the sandbox is no longer useful? I'm not aware of anything that has changed that would make it be obsolete.

Comment: @BillDubuque:  Originally repeated edits to a post would result in it being automatically converted to Community Wiki.  One could then appeal to a moderator (via custom flag) to have the conversion reversed.  This mechanism no longer operates on any SE sites.  I can find the Meta post/announcement of the change if it helps.

Comment: @hardmath That has nothing to do with the reasons that I created the sandbox. The primary motivations were to minimize noise on the front page, and to provide a reliable way to save drafts.

Comment: @BillDubuque:  You have a habit, perhaps unconsciously, to twist the words of others into absurdities and rebuke the straw men thus created.  Feel free to provide your own advice to the OP, but I offered no opinion as to your "reasons that I created the sandbox" nor did I state "the sandbox is no longer useful".

Comment: I think you could just add a new answer, I think. (It seems neither protected nor closed, so this should work fine. )

Comment: @quid:  The [current Sandbox](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4666/sandbox-for-drafts-of-long-complex-posts) is marked Closed for just this reason (to prevent new Answers).

Comment: @hardmath thanks I only saw the one on the frontpage now, and didn't know there are two sandboxes and the main one is indeed closed. Sorry for the confusion. I am not sure it is a good idea to have it closed. A request not to post answer when feasible (and to delete obsoelet ones)  should suffice. But this debate is likely off-topic here; I was just thinking out loud.// Added: actually both are on the front-page not sure how I overlooked that...

Comment: The history of the sandbox is very strange (perhaps one of the strangest affairs on meta). It was sparked by the MK fiasco, later suffered attempted forks, SE bugs, etc. However, it still serves a good purpose, so I find it quite puzzling that some users think it is obsolete.

Comment: @BillDubuque  But the one that now seems to be the "main" is not even the oldest; kennytm  had created one in July 2010. The history seems still more complex.

Comment: @quid The earlier sandbox was for formatting. It was an explicit decision to separate the drafts sandbox from the formatting sandbox since the latter might have TeX monstrosities that could slow down editing in the drafts sandbox. Iirc I mentioned some of this when I created the sandbox (in comments?) but it may be deleted by now.

Comment: @BillDubuque this difference escaped me. Thanks for the explanation.